# Using flash player i.e. watching a video in fullscreen (Mozilla), freezes computer

Tags: 14.04, firefox, flash

this has happened to me twice now, today and yesterday. I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 (some time ago) 64bit and I use noscript in Firefox.

I was watching youtube not in fullscreen and my screen froze but the sound kept on playing with no problem. At first I couldn't do anything but after mashing a lot of button combinations my mouse started working (the mashing did not result in anything but the mouse showing) I tried to shut the tab down with youtube and it worked, kind of. The sound stopped but the computer was still frozen apart from the cursor.

Today I was watching a stream in fullscreen and the same thing happened. Screen froze, sound kept on playing and after mashing button combinations (stuff like alt+f4, esc, alt+tab etc.) my cursor appeared but I could do nothing anyway.

I tried to find a solution but I only found posts from 2013, 2014 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Adobe Flash player support and updates for linux platform has been stopped. Therefore you might experience some problems.

As an alternative you should disable Flash plugin.

> 1. Press CTRL+SHIFT+A
> 2. Go to the PLUGIN section, and disable Shockwave flash player.
> 3. Reload the Youtube video. Now It will use HTML 5 player to play it.

I hope HTML5 player wont cause any trouble!